# DevExtreme dx data grid how to set scroll focus to last row in angular

Tags: angular

We are using DevExtreme grid for displaying certain data in Angular 15 project. It use signalr are to get grid refreshed automatically. We would like to set the scroll bar focus alway to last row as last row will have latest data. Would anyone please suggest how can I achieve it. Thank you

```
<dx-data-grid
id="employeeGrid"
height="auto"
[dataSource]="dataSource"
[showBorders]="false"
width="100%"
margin="auto"
sorting="false"
columnAutoWidth="true"
(onRowPrepared)="onRowPrepared($event)"
```

> 